# netbeans web service restful uri

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans, entities

I've a little and simple database and I would like to create some web services to understand netbeans wizard.

I've a three table:

- **Regione** (1:n) **Provincia** (1:n) **Comune**

When I get

```
http://myhost/webservices/regione
```

I have this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <regiones> 
       <regione> 
           <id>1</id> 
           <nome>Piemonte</nome> 
           <ripartizioneGeografica>NORD OCCIDENTALE</ripartizioneGeografica> 
       </regione> 
       <regione> 
           <id>2</id> 
           <nome>Valle d'Aosta</nome> 
           <ripartizioneGeografica>NORD OCCIDENTALE</ripartizioneGeografica> 
       </regione> 
       ........
   </regiones>
```

But I don't see any entry for "provincia" entity related in Regione. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://myhost/webservices/regione
```

ask for a list of all regiones. provincias is more detailed information of a region and would be requested by

```
http://myhost/webservices/regione/1

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <regione> 
    <id>1</id> 
    <nome>Piemonte</nome> 
    <ripartizioneGeografica>NORD OCCIDENTALE</ripartizioneGeografica>
    <provincias>
      <provincia>
         ...
      </provincia>
        ...
    </provincias>
  </regione>
```

xml generated from test project

```
<regionss uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss">
  <regions uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/1/">
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Region 1</name>
     <provincesCollection  uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/1/provincesCollection/">
         <provinces uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/1/provincesCollection/1/"/>
         <provinces uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/1/provincesCollection/2/"/>
     </provincesCollection>
   </regions>
   <regions uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/2/">
       <id>2</id>
       <name>Region 2</name>
       <provincesCollection uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/2/provincesCollection/">
            <provinces uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/2/provincesCollection/3/"/>
       </provincesCollection>
    </regions>
    <regions uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/3/">
         <id>3</id>
         <name>Region 3</name>
         <provincesCollection uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/3/provincesCollection/">
              <provinces uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/3/provincesCollection/4/"/>
              <provinces uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/3/provincesCollection/5/"/>
              <provinces uri="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/resources/regionss/3/provincesCollection/6/"/>
          </provincesCollection>
     </regions>
</regionss>
```

Comment: Ok, but into the Restful standard, could I be able to see a URI that identifies "provincia" resource?

Comment: U can add that url by modifying the generated classes. I will check what is generated by netbeans.

Comment: Just tried to generate the classes. The uri's should be generated too. In your converter classes there should be an URI field.